# Unable to select a specific html table using xpathSapply in R

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scrape the second table from the following link http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15

I have tried the following R code using the XML package:

```
    p_frango_resfriado <- htmlTreeParse("http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15", 
    useInternalNodes = TRUE, 
    encoding = "UTF-8")

    xpathSApply(p_frango_resfriado, "//table[@width = '95%']//tr//td[2]", xmlValue)
    xpathSApply(p_frango_resfriado, "//table[@width = '95%']//tr//td[3]", xmlValue)
    xpathSApply(p_frango_resfriado, "//table[@width = '95%']//tr//td[4]", xmlValue)
```

The problem is that this code scrapes both html tables in the webpage, and I only want to scrape the second one.  I have tried, the code below, which does not return anything interesting:

```
xpathSApply(p_frango_resfriado, 
"//a[text() = 'Preços do frango resfriado CEPEA/ESALQ - Estado SP']/table[@width = '95%']", 
xmlValue)
```

Could anyone please help me with this problem?  I am not very good with the XPath language and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Using `XML::xmlToDataFrame` with XPath query**

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
URL <- "http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))
```

The only difference between the two tables is the table names used in the xpath query

**Table 1: Preços do frango congelado CEPEA/ESALQ - Estado SP**

```
xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango congelado')]/../table/tr/td/font/tr"
```

**Table 2: Preços do frango resfriado CEPEA/ESALQ - Estado SP**

```
xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango resfriado')]/../table/tr/td/font/tr"

doc <- htmlParse(temp)
listofTableNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, xpexpr)
length_nodes <- length(listofTableNodes)
include_indices1 <- 1:(length_nodes - 2)

# create dataframe using xmlvalues of the nodelist. Both `getNodeSet()` 
# and `xpathSApply` will provide identical results.
# using `getNodeSet()`
df <- xmlToDataFrame(listofTableNodes[include_indices1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# using `xpathSApply`
df <- xmlToDataFrame(xpathSApply(doc, xpexpr)[include_indices1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# clean data
df$td <- as.Date(gsub("[Â ]\\s*", "", df$td), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df[, 4] <- gsub("\t$", '', df[, 4])

# add column names
xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango resfriado')]/../table/tr/td/font/text()"
# for Table-1
# xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango congelado')]/../table/tr/td/font/text()"
listofTableNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, xpexpr)
colnames(df) <- c('Date', sapply(listofTableNodes, xmlValue))
df
#            Date Valor R$ Var./dia Var./mÃªs
#   1  2016-08-17     4,37    0,46%     8,17%
#   2  2016-08-16     4,35    0,46%     7,67%
#   3  2016-08-15     4,33    0,46%     7,18%
#   4  2016-08-12     4,31    0,00%     6,68%
#   5  2016-08-11     4,31    0,70%     6,68%
#   6  2016-08-10     4,28    0,47%     5,94%
#   7  2016-08-09     4,26   -0,70%     5,45%
#   8  2016-08-08     4,29    3,87%     6,19%
#   9  2016-08-05     4,13    0,49%     2,23%
#   10 2016-08-04     4,11    0,00%     1,73%
#   11 2016-08-03     4,11    1,73%     1,73%
#   12 2016-08-02     4,04    0,00%     0,00%
#   13 2016-08-01     4,04    0,00%     0,00%
#   14 2016-07-29     4,04    0,00%    -0,49%
#   15 2016-07-28     4,04   -0,25%    -0,49%
```

**Note:** Everyday, the values are updated on this webpage, which will be taken into account using `length_nodes`.

## **Using `XML::readHTMLTable` without XPath query**

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
URL <- "http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))
df <- readHTMLTable(temp, stringAsFactors = FALSE, which = 8)
# Table 1
df[4:18,]
# Table 2
df[28:42,]
```

## **Using `XML::readHTMLTable` with XPath query**

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
URL <- "http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))
doc <- htmlParse(temp)

# XPath Query
# Table -1
xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango congelado')]/../table/tr/td/font"
df <- xpathSApply(doc, xpexpr, readHTMLTable)
include_indices <- 1:(nrow(df[[4]]) -4)
df <- df[[4]][include_indices,]

# Table-2
xpexpr <- "//center/a[contains(., 'do frango resfriado')]/../table/tr/td/font"
df <- xpathSApply(doc, xpexpr, readHTMLTable)
include_indices <- 1:(nrow(df[[4]]) -4)
df <- df[[4]][include_indices,]
```

Comment: Hi Sathish, thanks for the help, but if possible I would like to know the specific XPath expression that I need to pass in order to obtain second table.

Comment: From `df <- readHTMLTable(temp, which=1)` , I get: 
Error in readHTMLTable(temp, which = 1) : unused argument (which = 1), and it doesn't matter if I leave out the `which=1`, since then I get: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I wonder if different versions are an issue. I get `unused arguments (stringAsFactors = FALSE, which = 8)`. I'm using XML 3.98-1.4 which is what CRAN thinks is the current version.

Comment: @42- XML pkg version `packageVersion("XML"); `  `# [1] ‘3.98.1.4’`

Comment: After restart the error is now: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"list"’` But the method from chinsoon12 was effective.

Comment: `temp` is a list of 14 items, most of them are reported by str() as dataframes with names of "NULL"

Comment: Yes, that correct. Your code creates temp as str(temp) ...`
 chr "/var/folders/yq/m3j1jqtj6hq6s5mq_v0jn3s80000gn/T//Rtmp83VvLM/file166894f355e56.html"` and per my browser there is an html file at that location.

Comment: I get a warning from readLines : `Warning message:
In readLines(temp) : line 425 appears to contain an embedded nul`

Comment: `ht[1:5]` returns: `
[1] "<script>"                                                                         
[2] "  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){"   
[3] "  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o)," 
[4] "  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)"
[5] "  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');"`

Comment: Last 4 lines: ` tail(ht, 4)
[1] ""        ""        ""        "</html>"`

Comment: Since I used readLines it's a character vector and out of synce with your object structure. When I read it with readHTMLTable I'm still getting a list of 15 (mostly dataframes) all with names of "NULL". This is probably a Mac versus Linux issue and not something that is bothering me particularly. I think you have solved the problem for the OP and if you want to go back to something more useful to you, feel free.

Comment: When I look at the "data.frames", they are a mess;  the first (and second) tables of that webpage are contained in item 8 and all of the data (and none of the structure) is in a single row(2),column("V1") with no apparently parsing of "cell" or "row" separation a long.

Comment: Same messed up result. Is there a separator parameter to offer?

Comment: @42- This is not Mac vs Linux issue. I get a list of 14 data frames with `df <- readHTMLTable(temp)`. However I get  a data frame with `50 obs. of 4 variables` after using `df <- readHTMLTable(temp, stringAsFactors = FALSE, which = 8)`

Comment: Wait. That is still the same messed up table. df[2,"V1"] has the contents but not structure of the two tables on that page.

Comment: Your XML::xmlToDataFrame code does succeed and is very helpful. Maybe I can put a bounty on this to get you more than a single upvote.

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for the help, your edit did help me, but I still do not understand the functioning of the function contains, specifically why you wrote . (dot as the first argument.  I also do not understand why you must put /.. afterwards.  If you could clarify that it would help me a lot in understanding more about XPath.

Comment: @Rafolks xpath query has a basic syntax of `axis::node-test[predicate]` for every location steps

Comment: contains is a predicate which checks for the text in element a

Comment: once the correct table is identified, then `/..` will give us the parent element of the table. In this case, it will be the element <center>

Comment: @Sathish So in a[contains(., 'do frango resfriado')], the . is used to indicate that you are searching for the value contained in the a tag?

Comment: `a[contains(., 'do frango congelado')]` checks for the string `'do frango congelado'` inside element `a`. The `.` inside the parenthesis indicates the current node which is element a

Comment: In addition to `contains()`, there are many predicate function available in xpath language such as `last(), position(), count(), id(), name(), starts-with()` etc.,

Comment: @Sathish Ok, thanks a lot.  By the way, do you know any resource thath can help me with learning XPath/webscraping?  It seems difficult to find concise information for these types of doubts.

Comment: @Sathish I did not try readHTMLTable, I was actually more interested in the XPath expression needed to extract the table but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sathish Your readHTMLTable way of extracting the table works perfectly here

Answer (score 1):

This should work for now but i wonder if it will work robustly if you run it everyday.

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(XML)

#get website
tfile <- tempfile()
download.file("http://cepea.esalq.usp.br/frango/?page=379&Dias=15", tfile)
temp <- readHTMLTable(tfile)

#read in table
tbl <- temp[[5]][!is.na(temp[[5]]$V2) & !is.na(temp[[5]]$V4),]
tbl2 <- split(tbl, cumsum(tbl$V1==""))[[2]][-1,]
tbl2 

#perform formatting
colnames(tbl2) <- c("Date","Price","Pct1","Pct2")
tbl2 <- data.frame(apply(tbl2, c(1,2), function(x) {
    x <- gsub("Â","",x)
    x <- gsub(",",".",x,fixed=TRUE)
    x <- gsub("%","",x)
}))
tbl2$Date <- as.Date(tbl2$Date,"  %d/%m/%Y  ")
tbl2$Price <- as.numeric(tbl2$Price)
tbl2$Pct1 <- as.numeric(tbl2$Pct1) / 100
tbl2$Pct2 <- as.numeric(tbl2$Pct2) / 100
tbl2

#         Date Price    Pct1    Pct2
#65 2016-08-17  4.37  0.0046  0.0817
#66 2016-08-16  4.35  0.0046  0.0767
#67 2016-08-15  4.33  0.0046  0.0718
#68 2016-08-12  4.31  0.0000  0.0668
#69 2016-08-11  4.31  0.0070  0.0668
#70 2016-08-10  4.28  0.0047  0.0594
#71 2016-08-09  4.26 -0.0070  0.0545
#72 2016-08-08  4.29  0.0387  0.0619
#73 2016-08-05  4.13  0.0049  0.0223
#74 2016-08-04  4.11  0.0000  0.0173
#75 2016-08-03  4.11  0.0173  0.0173
#76 2016-08-02  4.04  0.0000  0.0000
#77 2016-08-01  4.04  0.0000  0.0000
#78 2016-07-29  4.04  0.0000 -0.0049
#79 2016-07-28  4.04 -0.0025 -0.0049
```

Comment: Still getting the same error as with the prior answer: `temp <- readHTMLTable(tfile)` ... Error in tb[["tbody"]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @42- are you able to open the tfile from your browser?

Comment: Oh, definitely. Tables display as expected. First thing I checked.

Comment: After restarting this now succeeds.